# What is the difference between xrefs and stack trace?

Tags: ida, functions, stack, callstack, call

In IDA, I can see what calls a specific function by looking at the xrefs to it, or by looking 1 step back on stack trace.

What are the differences between them?

How does IDA know what the stack trace is? And how does IDA know what the xrefs to a specific function are?

Answer (score 2):

x-refs is just a static cross-reference in the binary that can be identified during static-analysis.

So if you `main` call `funcA` you could tell that by looking at x-refs on `funcA`. But you can't be sure that it will be in fact called during runtime - there might be some conditional jumps that only call `funcA` in a certain state.

Stacktrace presents the actual calls at a given point so it's dynamic and might change after another instruction execution.

Stack trace information is gathered by looking at `EBP` on the stack [ref](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1412.shtml). x-refs are done by analyzing the binary.